# Is there a simple example of HQMF to QRDA cat 3 calculation?

Tags: javascript, ruby, xml, hl7

Where can I find a simple example of a clinical measure in HQMF xml format, which shows its result through the xml QRDA cat 3 standard?

I mean the flow process of calculation from HQMF to  QRDA..

Is there a tool that already does this?

I have searched and so far I found several testing tools, like cypress, popHealth and bonnie, but does anyone know what is the exact process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQMF documents are used to define the structure of a quality measure. They cannot really be converted to a QRDA. Generally a QRDA 3 file is the output result of calculating a set of patients against a quality measure against (which is defined by the HQMF).

A QRDA 3 will contain counts for how many patients met a certain component of a quality measure (Eg. the Initial Patient Population). Where an HQMF will describe how you go about performing the actual calculations.

There do exist tools that use patient data to perform measure calculations and produce QRDA3 files as a result. One such tool is popHealth. But we had enough problems helping clients with popHealth that we wrote our own - CQMsolution.

Cypress is only used to test the accuracy of your measure calculations. It will be used by the certification body. It generates random patients and you perform calculations on those patients which it then verifies. Bonnie is a component of popHealth and possibly Cypress as well.

I can do my best to answer questions here but one thing we do well is specialize in software and consulting for CQM calculations. Search CQMsolution or see my contact info.

Comment: Thank you SixOThree. Is it that CQMsolution an open source? is there an active community for discussion on subjects like this?

Comment: CQMsolution source is not freely available. It is written in C# and uses SQL Server. Though popHealth is open source and I believe the technology is Ruby on Rails to MongoDb.

Comment: The Cypress project has a discussion forum. It is meant for discussions related to the Cypress software but since the software has such a central role in certification the forum can often be a good place to ask for direction or more general questions. They also host bi-weekly tech talks with a question and answer periods which are suited guidance questions. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/project-cypress-talk

Comment: I have a general question. When you are using a relative database in SQL, you should adjust your data model to the HQMF elements are included? like patient characteristics, medications etc?

Comment: Just curious to know is there any sample  source or repository available for QRDA category 3 for 2015 edition ? ... It would be really great to get some samples for 2015 year

Comment: Hi you can check ecqi.